# How to filter by dayOfWeek in mongodb node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, dayofweek

I'm new at this, I need to get all the persons from the db that matches the day of the week of the attribute createdAt (a Date) and a day of the week obtained through a parameter in the request. My data model is:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    lastName: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    age: {
        required: true,
        type: Number
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

I'm working with MongoDB and Node.js

I've tried this:

```
        const people = await Person.aggregate(
            [{
                $addFields: {
                    dayyOfWeek: {
                        $dayOfWeek: "$createdAt"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $match: {
                    dayyOfWeek: {
                        $eq: req.params.weekday
                    }
                }
            }]
        )
```

and tried too with $where and $function in the find function, but it goes wrong because that gives me an error, "MongoError: $where is not allowed in this atlas tier"

Comment: What behavior/error/output did you get when using the aggregation pipeline in the question?

Comment: You may just need a simple `$expr` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zAg1L-2WFDh)

Comment: It should work, you can write even shorter `{ $match: { dayyOfWeek: req.params.weekday } }` Are you sure you get the error `MongoError: $where is not allowed in this atlas tier` at this aggregation pipeline?

Comment: I solved it, the problem was that req.params.weekday is a string, and when it compares the equality with dayyOfWeek, which belongs to the Person (an int), it fails. The solution was transform req.params.weekday to an int through parseInt. Thanks you for the comments!